# SELECT DISTINCT Not working Android SQLite

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

(NOTE question updated with what I have worked out so far)
I am writing an app that has locations recorded by the following:

```
id(primary), state, region, area, latitude, longitude
```

I can get all the data on the screen but I just want to list the states and only the states not any other data.  Also just one entry per unique entry.  ie 1 NSW for NSW not all 99 of them.  A user will  then select  the desired state they live in and it will then show a new table of data just for that state.  (by states I mean NSW, VIC, QLD etc)

The class' Dataprovider and recyclerview classes work fine too so I will keep that code out of it unless someone wants to see it.

Here is the Database class in question.

```
public class MyDatabase extends SQLiteAssetHelper {

private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "ReefData.db";
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

public MyDatabase(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    setForcedUpgrade();

}

public Cursor getData(){
    SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();
    SQLiteQueryBuilder qb = new SQLiteQueryBuilder();
    String [] sqlSelect = {"0 _id", "state", "area", "region", "latitude", "longitude"};
    String sqlTables = "Reefs";
    qb.setTables(sqlTables);
    Cursor c = qb.query(db, sqlSelect, null, null, null, null, null);
    c.moveToFirst();
    return c;
}}
```

So my first attempt was as follows:

```
String [] sqlSelect = {"0 _id", "state=DISTINCT", "area", "region", "latitude", "longitude"};
```

but that just gives me an error.

SO I changed it back to the orignal and modified the query as follows:

```
String [] sqlSelect = {"0 _id", "state", "area", "region", "latitude", "longitude"};
Cursor c = qb.query(db, sqlSelect, "state= 'TAS'", null, null, null, null);
```

And this works now just for TAS data.  I can even modify it with

```
Cursor c = qb.query(db, sqlSelect, "state= 'TAS' and region='Flinders Island'", null, null, null, null);
```

and it works great.

BUT, how can I get a list of just the states and only 1 of each.  I would of thought to do the following but it does not work:

```
Cursor c = qb.query(db, sqlSelect, "state = DISTINCT", null, null, null, null);
```

Any ideas?

UPDATE:  SO I have tried the following in the attached image so I am getting closer to the solution but not quite there.  Still need help to solve this.

[image]

Comment: what error does it give you?

Comment: Just when I run it I get:"Unfortunately, APPNAME has stopped. OK"

Comment: Ha you sound new, thats OK, I'll explain. I'm assuming you're using Android Studio. When you're phone is connected to the computer that is compiling your code, you can click on the Android Monitor tab at the bottom of the Android Studio program. Look for error logs (red text most likely) coming from your app. This will give you a bunch of details about what crashed and where (pointing to an exact line of code which caused the crash). Share that with us here and we can help you figure it out.

Comment: 11-21 12:25:54.030 12492-12492/? I/SQLiteAssetHelper: successfully opened database ReefData.db
11-21 12:25:54.031 12492-12492/? E/SQLiteLog: (1) unrecognized token: "[Ljava.lang.String;@ba8975b)"
11-21 12:25:54.031 12492-12492/? D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM

Comment: don't comment or answer with your errors. [edit] the post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**SOLVED!**

So [SQLiteQueryBuilder](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteQueryBuilder.html) methods that return a Cursor don't allow the **Boolean** parameter directly.

However after reading the class notes I noticed the method **setDistinct** and applied it to  the SQLiteQueryBuilder.

Now it works and gives me just one unique entry for each state, just what I was trying to do.  I did need to remove the other columns and just focus on the state, but thats another issue/solution not related to this question.  Suffice to say I had to focus on just the column state and apply the **setDistinct** to that column only to get the desired result.

Heres the completed code:

```
public Cursor getData(){
    SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();
    SQLiteQueryBuilder qb = new SQLiteQueryBuilder();
    String [] sqlSelect = {"0 _id", "state"};
    String sqlTables = "Reefs";
    qb.setTables(sqlTables);
    qb.setDistinct(true);
    Cursor c = qb.query(db, sqlSelect, null, null, null, null, null);
    c.moveToFirst();
    return c;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have an errant `0` in this line:

```
String [] sqlSelect = {"0 _id", "state", "area", "region", "latitude", "longitude"};`
                        ^here
```

I suspect you didn't intend to select a literal value, so you should remove it:

```
String [] sqlSelect = {"_id", "state", "area", "region", "latitude", "longitude"};`
```

If you *did* intend to select the literal value, then you need to separate it with a comma:

```
String [] sqlSelect = {"0", "_id", "state", "area", "region", "latitude", "longitude"};`
                          ^here
```

Comment: Hi Karakuri.  Interestingly "0 _id" works and the two options of "_id" and "0", "_id" both cause the SQLite error.   I will update the question to better reflect what my issue is and what I have worked out so far.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: @timv I don't see how that's possible, that literally should produce a syntax error, like the one in a stack trace that used to be part of your question.

Comment: still a newbie at sqlite so forgive my ignorance on that.  I know your right but I dont suppose you have an idea on my revised question?

Comment: Hi Karakuri,  here is the link to the sqliteassethelper that I am using and the "0 _id" is in the examples.  https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-sqlite-asset-helper/blob/master/samples/database-v1/src/main/java/com/example/MyDatabase.java