# SQliteQueryBuilder setDistinct does not include all unique values in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, sqlite

I solved an issue in a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40711225/select-distinct-not-working-android-sqlite/40753877#40753877) but now have a new issue based on what I now need to do.

I have about 900 rows in my database and the column in question is called **state**.  For the first page I just want to show the available states a user can tap on that then shows details for just that state on a new activity.  So I just select the state from the database and only show one entry for each state.  I do this as follows:

```
public Cursor getData(){
        SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();
        SQLiteQueryBuilder qb = new SQLiteQueryBuilder();
        String [] sqlSelect = {"0 _id", "state"};
        String sqlTables = "Reefs";
        qb.setTables(sqlTables);
        qb.setDistinct(true);
        Cursor c = qb.query(db, sqlSelect, null, null, null, null, null);
        c.moveToFirst();
        return c;
    }
```

**setDistinct** is set to **TRUE** so only one entry for each state is selected.

Here is my database screenshot and a limited version, but the issue is the same even on my original larger database.

[image]

Here is my emulator screenshot.

[image]

Thing is **New South Wales** does not show in the list.  Why would New South Wales be the  only state that seems to not show up.

Answer (score 0):

Rookie mistake by me.
I had the cursor statement as follows:

```
c.movetoFirst()
```

which is fine as it moves to the first entry.

BUT I then looped through the database as follows:

```
 reefs.moveToNext();
    do{
        StateDataProvider dataprovider = new StateDataProvider(reefs.getString(1));
        arrayList.add(dataprovider);
    } while (reefs.moveToNext());
```

I did not remove the

```
reefs.moveToNext()
```

as I had copied and pasted that code.

Once I removed the

```
reefs.moveToNext()
```

it all works just fine.