# selectionArgs error says column does not exist

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

So I have been wrestling with SQLite on android and have had a few issues resolved.  Issues are [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40776182/sqlitequerybuilder-setdistinct-does-not-include-all-unique-values-in-android-stu) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40711225/select-distinct-not-working-android-sqlite).

I now want to select DISTINCT regions for a given state.  My first RecyclerView screen shows the states just fine with the following code.

```
public Cursor getStateData() {
    SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();
    SQLiteQueryBuilder qb = new SQLiteQueryBuilder();
    String [] sqlSelect = {"0 _id", "state" };
    String sqlTables = "Reefs";
    qb.setTables(sqlTables);
    qb.setDistinct(true);
    Cursor c = qb.query(db, sqlSelect, null, null, null, null, null);
    c.moveToFirst();
    return c;
}
```

Now to get DISTINCT regions for each state I use the following code:

```
public Cursor getRegionData(String whichState) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();
    SQLiteQueryBuilder qb = new SQLiteQueryBuilder();
    String [] sqlSelect = {"0 _id", "region" };
    String theState = whichState;
    String sqlTables = "Reefs";
    qb.setTables(sqlTables);
    qb.setDistinct(true);
    Cursor c = qb.query(db, sqlSelect, theState , null , null, null, null);
    //  (table, columms to return,  colums for the where clause,  values for the where clause, null, null, null)
    c.moveToFirst();
    return c;
}
```

And it does not work and gives me this error message:

```
Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: Tasmania (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT DISTINCT 0 _id, region FROM Reefs WHERE (Tasmania)
```

I selected **Tasmania** from the list so **Tasmania** was passed in as the String argument **whichState**.

So if I was to describe the issue in purly SQL terms it goes like this:

```
SELECT
  region  //column in my table called region
FROM
  Reefs  // table in my database
WHERE
  state = [the state selected]  //column in my table called **state** which I pass in with the varible **whichState**
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why are you selecting `0` (constant)?

Comment: I am using SQLiteAssetHelper and being a newbie with SQLite have used the solution by these guys:  https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-sqlite-asset-helper

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're passing a value, not a `WHERE` clause, please refer to the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#query(boolean,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[],%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[],%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)).

To correct it, pass the `WHERE` clause and the arguments as such:

```
public Cursor getRegionData(String whichState) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();
    SQLiteQueryBuilder qb = new SQLiteQueryBuilder();
    String [] sqlSelect = {"0 _id", "region" };
    String [] theState = { whichState };
    String sqlTables = "Reefs";
    qb.setTables(sqlTables);
    qb.setDistinct(true);
    Cursor c = qb.query(db, sqlSelect, "state=?", theState, null, null, null);
    c.moveToFirst();
    return c;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, exactly my issue and now resolved.  Appreciate your time on answering so quickly.

Answer (score 0):

323go picked it perfectly.  Here is my complete code as it may help others with the same issue.

Interestingly I had the last method **getAreaData** sorted out just fine and it's slightly different so happy to be correctly on that code as I am a newbie with sql.

```
public Cursor getStateData() {
    SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();
    SQLiteQueryBuilder qb = new SQLiteQueryBuilder();
    String [] sqlSelect = {"0 _id", "state" };
    String sqlTables = "Reefs";
    qb.setTables(sqlTables);
    qb.setDistinct(true);
    Cursor c = qb.query(db, sqlSelect, null, null, null, null, null);
    c.moveToFirst();
    return c;
}

public Cursor getRegionData(String whichState) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();
    SQLiteQueryBuilder qb = new SQLiteQueryBuilder();
    String [] sqlSelect = {"0 _id", "region" };
    String [] theState = { whichState };
    String sqlTables = "Reefs";
    qb.setTables(sqlTables);
    qb.setDistinct(true);
    Cursor c = qb.query(db, sqlSelect, "state=?" , theState, null, null, null);
    //  (table, columms to return,  colums for the where clause,  values for the where clause, null, null, null)

    c.moveToFirst();
    return c;
}

public Cursor getAreaData(String whichState, String whichRegion) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();
    SQLiteQueryBuilder qb = new SQLiteQueryBuilder();
    String [] sqlSelect = {"0 _id", "state", "region", "area", "latitude", "longitude"};
    String sqlFilter = "state= '"+whichState+"' AND region= '"+whichRegion+"'";
    String [] sqlValues = {""};
    String sqlTables = "Reefs";
    qb.setTables(sqlTables);
    qb.setDistinct(true);
    Cursor c = qb.query(db, sqlSelect, sqlFilter, null, null, null, null);
    c.moveToFirst();
    return c;
}
```